# Excel VBA Merge multiple groups of cells at once

Tags: excel, vba

Here is the code I have:

```
Sub test()

Dim Mail As Range, Phys As Range, Books As Range, Records As Range

Set Mail = Range("A1:A3")
Set Phys = Range("B1:B3")
Set Books = Range("A4:D4")
Set Records = Range("C1:D3")

Union(Mail, Phys, Books, Records).Merge

End Sub
```

This code produces a single merged cell A1:D4 - I would like to merge A1:A3, B1:B3 etc such that there are 4 merged cells.

The only solution I can think of is to `.merge` each range separately:

```
Mail.Merge
Phys.Merge
Books.Merge
Records.Merge
... etc
```

But I think there must be a better way!

Comment: Can I take a step back and ask why you want to merge those cells? Merging cells can cause more headaches down the line if you want to do any analysis/data summaries.  I'm going to be this is an [XY Problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem).

Comment: Commenting here since I can't comment on the post you just deleted - specify `Option Explicit` at the top of every module, that will prevent the code from merrily compiling and attempting to run with typos. You were getting "Object required" because the runtime type of the undeclared variable was `Variant/Empty`, something you can't legally make a member call against.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why over complicate something? You can simply merge the cells as you stated in your question (See Sub: `OCCAMS_RAZOR`). If you wanted to do something elaborate, *which is over kill IMO*, you could loop through an array with predetermined ranges to be merged (See Sub: `OVER_KILL`).

The real question is, **why do you *need* these ranges to be merged?**

As mentioned by @BruceWayne, the cost of merging cells is high when it comes to analysis/summaries. Merged cells get in the way of simple cell references, formulas, and VBA. They also remove the option of summarizing data in tables/pivots - which means graphs need to be manually built. The point is, there are a lot of cons to be considered.

---

```
Sub OCCAMS_RAZOR()

Dim Mail As Range, Phys As Range, Books As Range, Records As Range

Set Mail = Range("A1:A3"): Mail.Merge
Set Phys = Range("B1:B3"): Phys.Merge
Set Books = Range("A4:D4"): Books.Merge
Set Records = Range("C1:D3"): Records.Merge

End Sub
```

```
Sub OVER_KILL()

Dim Arr: Arr = Array("A1:A3", "B1:B3", "A4:D4", "C1:D3")
Dim i As Long

For i = LBound(Arr) To UBound(Arr)
    Range(Arr(i)).Merge
Next i

End Sub
```

*On both subs, all `.Range`s need to be qualified with a worksheet*

Comment: The reason for the automated merges is a user requirement. It's to serve an expandable/customizable form. It has to be simple enough not to freak out anyone who doesn't use excel on a regular basis, so anyone who needs "two section Bs" instead of the default single section B can click a button and have it created. The merges are needed so the user can tab through the mandatory fields quickly. The worksheet is protected to prevent users screwing with the formatting so that the form is interpretable by keyers who process the forms which is why the macro is necessary.